# Probability of finding a monochromatic $r$-clique if the edges of $K_n$ are coloured with three colours

Tags: probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

I was asked the question

> The edges of the graph $K_n$ are coloured randomly with three colours (chosen with equal probability). What is the probability of finding a monochromatic $r$-clique in it?

What I did was I picked $r$ vertices out of $n$ in $\binom nr$ ways and with that came $\binom r2$ edges. This is an $r$-clique iff all the $\binom r2$ edges are monochromatic. But, the probability that $\binom r2$ edges are monochromatic when randomly coloured with three colours is
$$\binom nr \times 3\times \frac 1{3^{\binom r2}}$$
But, in this formula, if we put $r=3$ and $n=6$, we get
$$\binom 63\times 3\times \frac 1{3^{\binom 32}}=20\times 3\times \frac 1{27}>1$$
This is no surprise since in our counting argument, we have counted a lot of edges more than once. So, the expression we got is sort of an upper bound for the required probability.

But, I couldn't find any ways to sharpen this upper bound to reach the exact answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Also, [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) a result pointed out by Manuel Lafond in the comments that says that if $n$ is large enough compared to $r$, then the required probability is $1$.

Comment: For a partial answer, you can look at Ramsey's theorem (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem).  It says that if $n$ is large enough compared to $r$, then the probability is $1$.  For small $n$, I don't think anyone has come up with an exact probability, since otherwise we would know more Ramsey numbers.  But you'll get better bounds by looking at the probability that there is no monochromatic $r$-clique.

Comment: @ManuelLafond thanks for the comment. This is an interesting result.